# Sql server - xml column query returns result with multiple root elements

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an XML column in SQL Server table (SQL Server 2012) with following data:

```
<history>
   <status updatedAt="2013-09-01" />
   <status updatedAt="2013-08-12" />
   <status updatedAt="2013-05-10" />
   <status updatedAt="2013-04-01" />
</history>
```

The issue is, when I query it with an XQuery expression, for example:

```
SELECT Statuses = StatusHistory.query('/history/status[@updatedAt >= @sql:variable("@start") and @updatedAt <= @sql:variable("@end")]')
```

the following result is returned:

```
<status updatedAt="2013-08-12" />
<status updatedAt="2013-05-10" />
```

which is not valid xml(contains multiple root elements).

Is there any way to wrap the `query()` method's result in a single root, or to preserve the original xml structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a single XML result, but a sequence of XML fragments which are each well-formed XML (technically it cannot be valid without any schema, also the posted input is well-formed, not valid).

XQuery allows to construct new results:

```
SELECT Statuses = StatusHistory.query('
    <history>
    {
        /history/status
        [
            @updatedAt >= @sql:variable("@start") and 
            @updatedAt <= @sql:variable("@end"  )
        ]
    }
    </history>
')
```

As an alternative you could create a copy of the XML fragment and delete all nodes you do *not* want, but I think this solution is more straight-forward.